# See individual Google Shopping products performances in Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads, shopping

I'm running a Google Shopping for search campaign in Adwords. So the products are pulled in from my merchant center and displayed with a picture in the SERPs.

In Google Analytics or Adwords I can not distinguish the performance of individual products. Both Adwords and Analytics shows only cpc and conversion numbers for the whole campaign.

I would like to see which products perform well and which don't.

Answer (score 1):

Gooogle Analytics can show you the performance by product if each your your products is on its own page.  All you need to do is set the secondary dimension of your campaign report to "Landing Page".  Then Google Analytics will break out your campaign by which page the visitor landed on when they came to your site:

[image: campaign report secondary dimension: landing page]

It will even show you your  goal metrics by campaign landing page.